Using a 20 amp diode in the alternator line, will it shut off the motor using a kill switch? If so how to install the diode?
My husband’s car is a 1967 Camaro used on street and for drag racing.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Where is the kill switch installed? You don't need a diode to install a kill switch and putting it in the right place. Put a kill switch in line for power to the distributor. Flip the switch and the engine is dead. Not a distributor engine? We need to know this information to answer your question.

Seems likely a mere 20A diode from the alternator to the battery will die a horrible death pretty much immediately after starting.

I think you are referring to NHRA rules for certain classes of drag racing that require a kill switch for driver and first responder safety after a crash.
The short answer is No, using just a 20 amp diode in the alternator line will not create a kill switch. You also have to install a kill switch of a particular design in a particular location to comply with NHRA rules.
If a racing kill switch is wired to disconnect just the battery, the car can continue to run on electricity generated by the alternator. A diode can prevent this continued operation. This forum discussion may shed more light on the subject for you.
Suggest you follow the instructions that come with the kill switch
